Firebase push notifications not functioning well
My app has a chatroom where users can receive notifications for each message it was working fine and I didn’t change anything but now users only receive general notifications i sent through firebase console and chatroom notifications aren’t functioning very well , in firebase console i see firebase received the functions from chatroom notifications but there is an error saying unknown server… any idea ?!
i checked the bill history and there is no outstanding bill or anything regarding that, checked with multiple devices android and ios still same problem

While there are many factors to consider when dealing with an error of unknown server, here are workarounds you can try to resolve the issue:

Based on the answer of Umair Khan to this Stack Overflow question, ensure that there’s an uploaded APNs Production Certificate to Apple App Configuration, and if there’s no uploaded APNs certificate then generate a new production certificate and upload it. To do this:

Go to Firebase

Select Project Settings and then,

Select Cloud Messaging tab

Scroll down to Apple App configuration,  click the Upload button in APNs authentication key.
Full detail here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key


Also, Umair Khan suggests uploading an APNs Authentication Key instead of certificates. Jas chu added that you can locate your keys at Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles on developer apple page: https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list

Monitor the token refresh, to be able to notify whether the token is updated.
Register the delegate and add the proper delegate method


func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
      print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
    
      let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
      NotificationCenter.default.post(
        name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
        object: nil,
        userInfo: dataDict
      )
      // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
      // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }

For Apple platforms: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#monitor-token-refresh
The onNewToken callback fires whenever a new token is generated.
       override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: $token")
        sendRegistrationToServer(token)
}

Preview of sample code for Android: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#monitor-token-generation

Keep in mind that to be able to receive Messages sent from Firebase console, Application must be in background. For apps in the foreground, messages are handled by a callback function.

More detail at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Check if you have a method of sendToDevice, this method is deprecated. Google now  recommends using the send method instead. The send method has been available since SDK version 6.0.0.

Check out this sample code from Lhony to this Stack Overflow question.
    const message = {
        notification: {
            title: title,
            body: body,
        },
        data: {
            title: title,
        },
        token: pushToken
    };
    await firebase.messaging.send(message);


In your app’s Info.plist file, set

    FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = YES

I highly recommend following the guide on Setting up a Firebase Cloud Messaging documentation and everything should work as expected.
